# How can I increase the height of a div to fit the content?

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive, materialize

How can I make a div increases its height to fit the text contained in it as the user decreases the width of the browser window? Since I cannot let decrease the font-size, and after a certain width the container should maintain an aspect ratio, I'm a little bit lost on it.

I'm using MaterializeCSS and I tried using the `card-content` class for it, as well as a `min-height` tag for the card itself.

```css
#about-us-desktop-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 20vw;
  width: 73vw;
}
.big-card {
  padding-bottom: 5.847vw;
  min-height: 35.88194444444444vw;
}
.brush-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 69px;
  left: 9vw;
  width: 72px;
}
.leaf-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 69.7px;
  left: 8vw;
  width: 68.6px;
  height: 65.6px;
}
.heart-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5vw;
  top: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}
.about-us-info {
  position: relative;
}
.about-us-text-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 191.3px;
  min-height: 15.972222vw;
  border-left: #E7E7E7 solid 2px;
  padding-left: 3.611111112vw;
}
.about-us-caption {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
}
.about-us-text {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 36.3px;
  color: #9A9A9A !important;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 237.6px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 32px !important;
}
.first-text-container {
  border: 0 !important;
  left: 1.38vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="about-us-desktop-container">
  <div class="col s12 card big-card z-depth-2">
    <div class="row card-content">
      <div class="col s4">
        <div class="about-us-info center">
          <img class="brush-icon info-icon" src="public/brush.svg" />
          <div class="about-us-text-container first-text-container">
            <p class="about-us-caption flow-text">Lorem by
              <br/>99 amet egestas</p>
            <p class="about-us-text light">Aenean feugiat erat vel euismod feugiat. Aenean ut lectus iaculis, dignissim dui vitae, varius nibh!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s4">
        <div class="about-us-info center">
          <img class="leaf-icon info-icon" src="public/leaf.svg" />
          <div class="about-us-text-container">
            <p class="about-us-caption flow-text">Lorem Ipsum
              <br/>Aliquame</p>
            <p class="about-us-text light flow-text">mattis metus sed enim luctus, nec aliquam sapien pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus ipsum a maximus laoreet</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s4">
        <div class="about-us-info center">
          <img class="heart-icon info-icon" src="public/heart.svg" />
          <div class="about-us-text-container">
            <p class="about-us-caption flow-text">Only 20 Ipsum
              <br/>in the Lorem!</p>
            <p class="about-us-text light flow-text">Nec elit nec suscipit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus efficitur et lorem non gravida. Vivamus pharetra blandit sagittis</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[And here is the result I'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy8Gx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you move your image with position absolute. With this operator the div elements don't recognize them as part of the content. Also you pushed your text down with position relative and top which the div doesn't recognize. Try to rather float your elements.

Comment: but, doesnt the float property also take elements out of their contexts? i tested that and didnt work, nonetheless, the absolute-positioning remark you made helped me achieve what i wanted.